# How to a link in all of your articles after you publish them

Tags: html, css, joomla

i have a joomla! based website,and i published thousands of articles in it. but now, i need to add a link to all of the articles,and im sure you know its not possible to edit thousands of articles 1 by 1.

all of my articles are using the same class and style, for example:

```
<div class="table-border">
<table class="article" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
       <tr class="thead">
  <td class="col1">TITLE GOES HERE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even" dir="rtl">
  <td> CONTENT GOES HERE </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

now i want to know,is there a way to call a class or a link in css? (like when you set background image in css)

any help in anyway (css, php, html solutions, etc.) would be appreciated.

Comment: As a side note, instead of `<table class="article">` I'd consider using `<article>`.

Comment: you just need a link for each article or a link that will then contain all of your articles?

Comment: >Cyzanfar. i need all of my articles to contain a link. for example, they all contain www.google.com in their header, or anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add in your template file:

```
<?php
  if (JRequest::getVar('option') == 'com_content' && JRequest::getVar('view') == 'article') {
  echo '<a href="#">LINK</a>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: well it seems that you are good with coding. can i ask you another question plz? if yes, then here is the Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347699/layout-probiem-with-different-browsers     tnx.